# chktex warning: You ought to not use primitive TeX in LaTeX code

Tags: warnings, chktex

What is the meaning of the following chktex warning in this example?

> 41: You ought to not use primitive TeX in LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{amsmath}    

\begin{document}    
\begin{align*}
  \bordermatrix{
      & X & Y \cr
  X & 0 & 0 \cr
  Y & 0 & 0 \cr
  } \qquad
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

How should I fix it? Replacing `\cr` with `\\` does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should always bear in mind that ChkTeX was never meant to be (and never could be) fool-proof.  You have several options.

1. Use something besides `\bordermatrix` as in @egreg's answer.
2. Use (multiple) line suppressions as in @egreg's answer.
3. Use (a single) file suppression: `% chktex-file 41` somewhere before the first use.  This will turn it off entirely for this file.
4. Turn off the warning for all files in your chktexrc file.  Simply add `--nowarn 41` to the `CmdLine` section.
5. Remove `\cr` from the list of primitive commands that should be avoided.

The last is the hardest, because ChkTeX currently doesn't have a way to remove from a list, so you'll have to overwrite the list entirely with a section something like:

```
Primitives = {
   \above \advance \catcode \chardef \closein \closeout \copy \count
   \countdef 
   # \cr 
   \crcr \csname \delcode \dimendef \dimen \divide
   \expandafter \font \hskip \vskip \openout

   # You might consider adding other obsolete commands which are not there by default...
   \rm \it \bf \sf \tt \em
}
```

Full Disclosure: I'm the current maintainer of ChkTeX.

Comment: I don't think that suggesting to globally suppress warning 41 is the answer. What I'd like to have is a situation such as in my answer, where I don't want to be warned about a usage I'm *well aware* of. What's needed is the ability to suppress warnings in the preamble.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in the preamble".  Is that different than #3?  Do you have a suggested syntax?  I'm happy to consider other ways of suppressing warnings that aren't useful, since I think false positives are very annoying.

Comment: I mean suppressing warnings for code before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Try `chktex -H0`.  Perhaps that should be the default, but I hate to change the defaults at this point--I just put everything in my .chktexrc file.  Also, thanks for taking the time to engage.

Answer (score 2):

I find `chktex` unbearable. Anyway, you can make `\bordermatrix` to accept `\\` instead of `\cr`. But you have to suppress the check in two lines.

Particularly annoying is that you can, in principle, suppress a warning by adding a suitable comment, which is shown nonetheless unless you suppress all warnings of type 22. This is very silly, isn't it?

I also added an alternative to `\bordermatrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray} % for an alternative to \bordermatrix
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\bordermatrix}{\cr}{\\}{}{} % chktex 41
\patchcmd{\bordermatrix}{\cr}{\\}{}{} % chktex 41

\begin{document}


\[
\bordermatrix{
    & X & Y \\
  X & 0 & 0 \\
  Y & 0 & 0
}
\qquad
\begin{blockarray}{ccc}
    & X & Y \\
  \begin{block}{c(cc)}
  X & 0 & 0 \\
  Y & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

If I call `chktex -wall -n22 juan.tex`, I get no warning.

[image]

Comment: "I find chktex unbearable." Now i'm curious as to why :)

Comment: @Lupino See the second paragraph. `;-)` Besides this, warnings should be suppressed in the preamble.

Comment: So, if you write `% chktex 41` behind a "bad" cs, chktex is fine with it, unless you tell it to suppress type-22-warnings; then it is not? Seem's legit...

Comment: @Lupino With just `% chktex 41` the output shows `Warning 22 in juan.tex line 6: Comment displayed.` on one line and `\patchcmd{\bordermatrix}{\cr}{\\}{}{} % chktex 41` on the following line, which defeats suppressing the warning. And one can't use `chktex 22` to suppress the warning about the comment. Silly.

Comment: Warning 22 (warning about comments, which is ridiculous in my opinion), should *not* be on by default.  If it is, then you need to contact whoever packaged ChkTeX and tell them to fix it.  If you're running with -wall, then I guess you get what you asked for.  As for not being able to suppress warning 22, that's arguably a bug and you should report it if you care.  Full Disclosure: I'm the current maintainer of ChkTeX.

Comment: @IvanAndrus Well, if I don't use `-wall`, I get nothing at all.